# Cannot read property 'has' of undefined in Dolby Interactivity APIs Client SDK

Tags: reactjs, web-audio-api, video-conferencing, dolby, dolby-audio-api

I am building a video conferencing app using Dolby Interactivity API's.

I tried using Dolby Interactivity APIs Client SDK in my react app. I followed the docs given here:
https://dolby.io/developers/interactivity-apis/reference/client-ux-kit/uxkit-voxeet-react

The home page loads  well but when I join the call, page crashes with error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
at c.value (bundle.js:22)
at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:27)
at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:28)
at beginWork (bundle.js:28)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:2)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:8)
at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:27)
at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:27)
at workLoopSync (bundle.js:27)
at renderRootSync (bundle.js:27)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (bundle.js:27)
at bundle.js:14
at unstable_runWithPriority (react-dom.development.js:1009)
at runWithPriority$1 (bundle.js:14)
at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (bundle.js:14)
at flushSyncCallbackQueue (bundle.js:15)
at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (bundle.js:27)
at Object.enqueueSetState (bundle.js:15)
at u.webpackHotUpdate../node_modules/@voxeet/react-components/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:325)
at u.c.onStateChange (bundle.js:1)
at Object.notify (bundle.js:1)
at e.t.notifyNestedSubs (bundle.js:1)
at u.c.onStateChange (bundle.js:1)
at dispatch (redux.js:222)
at index.js:11
at dispatch (redux.js:638)
at bundle.js:1
```

I've looked into their docs a little bit more but unable to find the issue. If anyone has used this tool before or has any knowledge regarding this, kindly help me fix this issue.

App.js File:

```
import { reducer as voxeetReducer } from "@voxeet/react-components"
import React from "react"
import thunkMidleware from "redux-thunk"
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux"

import { ConferenceRoom, VoxeetProvider } from "@voxeet/react-components"

import "@voxeet/react-components/dist/voxeet-react-components.css"

const reducers = combineReducers({
  voxeet: voxeetReducer,
})

const configureStore = () =>         
createStore(reducers,applyMiddleware(thunkMidleware))

const settings = {
  consumerKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  consumerSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  conferenceAlias: "Sample",
}

function App() {
  return (
    <VoxeetProvider store={configureStore()}>
      <ConferenceRoom
        autoJoin
        consumerKey={settings.consumerKey}
        consumerSecret={settings.consumerSecret}
        conferenceAlias={settings.conferenceAlias}
      />
    </VoxeetProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: there is no enough information in your question. Please add some snippets of code to your question.

Comment: Added the App.js file code snip. That's all the code that I'm trying to run.